# Numbering \subsubsection in report class

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I used the `\subsubsection` command hoping that LaTeX would add a subsection inside a section

```
\subsubsection{sub sub section}
```

But it just made the text within the `{}` bold. It did not give it a subsubsection number. My document class is `report`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
```

Could someone please help me to fix this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you want to include `\subsubsection` in the numbering, you have to change the depth of numbering this way:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```

in the preamble, and... that's it, since 3 is the level of the subsubsection.

Answer (score 31):

By default, the lowest sectioning level that is numbered is `\subsection` (level 2)  in the `book` and `report` classes, and `\subsubsection` (level 3)  in the `article` class. To number `\subsubsection`s in `report`, add the following to your preamble:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```