# How to change the spacing between numbering and text in subsection

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, scrreprt

I am a Master student and currently I am writing the thesis. My University did provide a template but it is in Microsoft Office Word but I am using latex. The attached figure is the example of the heading and the table of content. [image: Heading sample] [image: TOC sample]
I need the word CHAPTER 1 and INTRODUCTION set to center but the section remain on the left. Besides, the `\tableofcontents` generate a different style of TOC compare the template of my University. Any suggestion and modification to make thing works?
Thank You.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1.5in,rmargin=1.in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\section{What is a flow}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The reason I used `\subsection*{1.1 What is flow}` is to avoid the default numbering as it shown 0.0.1 but I need 1.1.

Comment: It will be the same question, I do not need numbering for Chapter1, and Introduction which is shown in the attached figure. That is the reason I used asterisk because I am don't know how to do that.

Comment: You are doing this all wrong. It starts with an unnumbered chapter that you number by hand. Please read an introduction to LaTeX.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to completely change the requirements of an answer. Rather ask a new question instead.

Comment: And please do ask only one question per question. For ToC configuration please ask another question (if you cannot find a similar one that already answers your question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note, you *should not* do the numbering of chapters, sections and subsections manually. One of the basic features of LaTeX is, that numbering is done automatically, table of contents is done automatically and also cross references from one section to another is done automatically. All these things are configurable. One feature of KOMA-Script is, that a lot of things are highly configurable. But this needs to use the correct commands. Without using the correct commands you would have to do almost everything manually. This is nothing you would like.

Chapter headings with prefix line "Chapter *Nr.*" can be used with KOMA-Script option `chapterprefix`. And then you can reconfigure the font sizes, the horizontal and vertical skips and several other attributes of the headings. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
% a4paper,% Can be removed, because it is the default.
  chapterprefix,% Use chapter headings with prefix line (see scrguien.pdf).
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1.5in,rmargin=1.in]{geometry}
% margin (must you use such an ugly margin setup?
% \usepackage{times}% http://ctan.org/pkg/times
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}% times is obsolete this is one of the alternatives
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries}% \sectfont is deprecated (see scrguien.pdf)
\usepackage{scrhack}% to improve e.g. setspace (see scrguien.pdf).
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}% You can setup \onehalfspacing already loading the package.
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}% Note: The option also influences the ToC, LoF, LoT etc.
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym}
\pagenumbering{roman}% seems scrbook would be the better choice
\renewcommand*{\raggedchapter}{\centering}% Avoid usage of sectsty to reduce
                                % the possibility of compatibility issues.
\RedeclareSectionCommand[innerskip=\baselineskip,afterskip=\baselineskip,font=\normalsize,prefixfont=\normalsize]{chapter}% see scrguien.pdf
\RedeclareSectionCommands[beforeskip=-\baselineskip,afterskip=\baselineskip,font=\normalsize]{section,subsection}% see scrguien.pdf
% changes of headings number format:
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{% add \MakeUppercase to the original definition
  \mbox{%
    \MakeUppercase{% added
      \chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}%
    }%
    \thechapter\autodot
    \IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip}}%
}
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
  \makebox[3em][l]{\thesection\autodot}% 3em is the width resevered for the number
}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{%
  \makebox[3em][l]{\thesubsection\autodot}% 3em is the width resevered for the number
}


\usepackage{blindtext}% for example dummy text only
\begin{document}
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\section{What is flow}
\blindtext
\section{Gravity current}
\blindtext
\subsection{Compositional gravity current}
\blindtext
\subsection{ Particle-driven current}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

resulting in:

[image: two pages of the example document]

Please read an introduction to LaTeX and after the introduction the documentation of the used commands and options in the KOMA-Script manual.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. That's the format I need. But the top header spacing gap is too big, may I know which is the section I need to edit to reduce the gap?
Thank you.

Comment: @K3iTH You mean the space above the `\chapter` heading? In this case add an appropriate `beforeskip` value to the `\RedeclareSectionCommand[…]{chapter}` command. Please read the documentation of the command in den manual before.

Comment: Ya is the spacing about the work CHAPTER 1. There is a spacing gap when you compare page 1 and page 2 side by side. The text on page 2 is slightly higher than CHAPTER 1 on page 1.

Thanks for the explanation. I will read the documentation of the command to understand and learn more.

Comment: Hi there, I manage to adjust the spacing to match the required template, but I am facing another problem to add subsubsection. I follow the code by replacing subsection to subsubsection and added subsubsection to the `\RedeclareSectionCommands` and added renewcommand, but the heading is generated with text and without the number. I tried to change to the number for the width reserved for the number but still no luck. Thank You

Comment: @K3iTH If you have an additional question, please [ask a new question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and add a link from that new question to the question/answer here, if this would be useful. Currently, I do not understand your question from you last comment. Maybe you are searching for [`secnumdepth`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42161/numbering-subsubsection-in-report-class)???