# Setting the tables under correct subsubsections

Tags: tables, document-configuration

I am writing my master thesis via Latex and I am not able to put my tables under correct subsections. There is similar question and the suggestion was to use clear page but the problems is that the three tables became very far from each other when they can be under each other in one page. Is there a way to fix this.

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper, twoside]{report} % 'twoside' when printing

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % UTF-8 input
\usepackage[english]{babel}             % Set language to english
\usepackage{blindtext}                  % Use \Blinddocument or \blindmathpaper
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}               
\usepackage{hyperref}               
\usepackage{amsmath}            
\usepackage{amsfonts}               
\usepackage{amsthm}                 
\usepackage{gensymb}                
\usepackage{enumitem}               
\usepackage{mathtools}              
\usepackage{color}                  

\usepackage{pdfpages}               
\usepackage{parskip}                
\usepackage{multicol}                   
\usepackage[sharp]{easylist}        
\usepackage{makeidx}                
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}                    
\usepackage{listings}                   
\usepackage{etoolbox}                   
\usepackage[expansion=false]{microtype} 
\usepackage[toc, page]{appendix}                
\usepackage{framed}                 
\usepackage{multirow}               
\usepackage{afterpage}              
\usepackage{blindtext}              

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{floatrow, makecell}%
% Declare first page in every chapter as 'fancy' pagestyle
\makeatletter


\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi

    \thispagestyle{fancy}%
    \global\@topnum\z@
    \@afterindentfalse
    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Global Sensitivity Analysis}
\section{Sensitivity analysis of the Non-dimensional model}
\subsection{Sobol method}
\subsubsection{$x$}
\subsubsection{$y_{1}$}
\subsubsection{$y_{2}$}

\subsection{Random Balance Designs Fourier Amplitude Sensitivity Test method}
\subsubsection{$x$}


\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Max value of $x$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$} \\ 
            \midrule
            $x_{0}$        &  0.999823 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  &  0.000322 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    &  0.000266 \\
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.000147 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.000047 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.000037 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ &  0.000032 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.000019 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ & -0.000004 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  & -0.000086 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  & -0.000192 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}\hfill
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Mean value of $x$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$} \\
            \midrule
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.071375 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.003340 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    &  0.001563 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.001520 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.001247 \\
            $x_{0}$        &  0.001150 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ &  0.000282 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  &  0.000075 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  &  0.000013 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  & -0.000095 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ & -0.000232 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}\hfill
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Median value of $x$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$} \\
            \midrule
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.067302 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.003395 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.001542 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    &  0.001426 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.001322 \\
            $x_{0}$        &  0.000893 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ &  0.000173 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  &  0.000083 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  & -0.000015 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  & -0.000066 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ & -0.000212 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular} 
    \end{subtable}\hfill
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Eqm. value of $x$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &   $S_{1}$ \\
            \midrule
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.004223 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  &  0.000382 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.000229 \\
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.000131 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    &  0.000109 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  &  0.000011 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ & -0.000013 \\
            $x_{0}$        & -0.000037 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  & -0.000089 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ & -0.000129 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  & -0.000141 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}
    \caption{Sesitivity of $x$.}
\end{table}

\subsubsection{$y_{1}$}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Max value of $y_{1}$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$}  \\
            \midrule
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  &  0.999839 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  &  0.000198 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  &  0.000151 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ &  0.000077 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.000009 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    & -0.000034 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  & -0.000035 \\
            $x_{0}$        & -0.000046 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ & -0.000093 \\
            $\beta_{2}$    & -0.000139 \\
            $g_{12}$       & -0.000249 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}\hfill
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Mean value of $y_{1}$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$}  \\
            \midrule
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.075955 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.002982 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  &  0.002090 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.001381 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    &  0.001270 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.000597 \\
            $x_{0}$        &  0.000273 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ &  0.000103 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  &  0.000057 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  & -0.000031 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ & -0.000053 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}\hfill
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Median value of $y_{1}$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$}  \\
            \midrule
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.072321 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.002983 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  &  0.001799 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.001496 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    &  0.001112 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.000621 \\
            $x_{0}$        &  0.000278 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  &  0.000067 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ &  0.000046 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ & -0.000025 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  & -0.000034 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}\hfill
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Eqm. value of $y_{1}$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$}  \\
            \midrule
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.070960 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.002951 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  &  0.001774 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.001540 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    &  0.001182 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.000605 \\
            $x_{0}$        &  0.000255 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ &  0.000077 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  &  0.000034 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ & -0.000012 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  & -0.000020 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}
    \caption{Sesitivity of $y_{1}$.}
\end{table}

\subsubsection{ $y_{2}$}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Max value of $y_{2}$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$}  \\
            \midrule
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.999839 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.000432 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  &  0.000172 \\
            $x_{0}$        &  0.000110 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ &  0.000104 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  &  0.000063 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ &  0.000018 \\
            $g_{12}$       & -0.000060 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    & -0.000154 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  & -0.000164 \\
            $\beta_{2}$    & -0.000174 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}\hfill
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Mean value of $y_{2}$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$}  \\
            \midrule
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.078556 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.004368 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.003232 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    &  0.001764 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.001399 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ &  0.000124 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  &  0.000072 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  &  0.000064 \\
            $x_{0}$        &  0.000063 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  & -0.000141 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ & -0.000146 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}\hfill
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Median value of $y_{2}$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$}  \\
            \midrule
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.075486 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.004046 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.003262 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    &  0.001588 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.001538 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ &  0.000075 \\
            $x_{0}$        &  0.000066 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  &  0.000063 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  &  0.000061 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  & -0.000132 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ & -0.000144 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}\hfill
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Eqm. value of $y_{2}$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$}  \\
            \midrule
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.074109 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.003934 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.003281 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    &  0.001676 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.001576 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ &  0.000100 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  &  0.000069 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  &  0.000043 \\
            $x_{0}$        &  0.000039 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  & -0.000113 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ & -0.000141 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}
    \caption{Sesitivity of $y_{2}$.}
\end{table}
\subsection{Delta Moment-Independent Measure}
\subsubsection{$x$}
\subsubsection{$y_{1}$}
\subsubsection{$y_{2}$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your document example is not complete (missed is `\documentclas{...}`). In preamble you load some package twice or even three time, packages are not loaded in correct order, etc. Please make your document example compilable and minimal as much as is possible.

Comment: @Zarko I tried to fix it and it is executable now and I don't know what is the correct order of loading packages

Comment: Your tables are on right place, however your `\subsubsection` doeant show up. That you can see them, you need in preamble to add `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42161/numbering-subsubsection-in-report-class.

Comment: @Zarko without using clear page they get placed under different subsection and the other pb is that each subsubsection is on one page when there is a place for two of them  in one page

Comment: you are using `\begin{table}[h]` which means that the tables are quite likely to go to the end of the document as you are preventing them going to the top or bottom of a page, or to a page just of tables. `[htbp]` gives latex a much better chance to place them.

Comment: @David Carlisle To be honest I didn't know what refered .I changed to [htbp] but they are not placed under subsubsections without using \clearpage

Comment: I tested your file (with only related package) without using `\clearpage` command but with use of the table placement `[ht]`. The result was fine. However, in section you have only tables, no text. This can cause problems since LaTeX expect that on each page should be about 30% of text. See https://aty.sdsu.edu/bibliog/latex/floats.html

Comment: you don't need to use `table` you could just use `tabular` if they should be _in_ a subsection. The only purpose of the `table` environment is to take its content out of the man document flow and allow it to be re-inserted elsewhere to help with page breaking.

Comment: @ David Carlisle all are tabular and I need captions for all my tables as well and not sure if it is possible in tabualr

Answer (score 1):

To long for comment ...

As I mentioned in my comments, you need first to enable `subsubcaption` in your document (by adding `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` into document preamble. Than may be sensible to define new limits of table numbers on page and fractions of text on non floats pages (for details see [Controlling LaTeX Floats](https://aty.sdsu.edu/bibliog/latex/floats.html)). Of course you also need to change options for floats placement to `[ht]`::

```
\setcounter{topnumber}{3}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{3}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{4}     % 5 ?
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.07}  % allow minimal text w. figs
```

Considering this MWE based on your document example can be:

```
\documentclass{report} % 'twoside' when printing
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % <---

    \setcounter{topnumber}{3}
    \setcounter{bottomnumber}{3}
    \setcounter{totalnumber}{4}     % 5 ?
    \renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.07}  % allow minimal text w. figs

\begin{document}
\chapter{Global Sensitivity Analysis}
\section{Sensitivity analysis of the Non-dimensional model}
\subsection{Sobol method}
\subsubsection{$x$}
\subsubsection{$y_{1}$}
\subsubsection{$y_{2}$}

\subsection{Random Balance Designs Fourier Amplitude Sensitivity Test method}

\subsubsection{$x$}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Max value of $x$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$} \\
            \midrule
            $x_{0}$        &  0.999823 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  &  0.000322 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    &  0.000266 \\
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.000147 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.000047 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.000037 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ &  0.000032 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.000019 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ & -0.000004 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  & -0.000086 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  & -0.000192 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}\hfill
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Mean value of $x$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$} \\
            \midrule
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.071375 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.003340 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    &  0.001563 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.001520 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.001247 \\
            $x_{0}$        &  0.001150 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ &  0.000282 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  &  0.000075 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  &  0.000013 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  & -0.000095 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ & -0.000232 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}\hfill
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Median value of $x$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$} \\
            \midrule
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.067302 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.003395 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.001542 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    &  0.001426 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.001322 \\
            $x_{0}$        &  0.000893 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ &  0.000173 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  &  0.000083 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  & -0.000015 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  & -0.000066 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ & -0.000212 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}\hfill
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Eqm. value of $x$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &   $S_{1}$ \\
            \midrule
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.004223 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  &  0.000382 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.000229 \\
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.000131 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    &  0.000109 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  &  0.000011 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ & -0.000013 \\
            $x_{0}$        & -0.000037 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  & -0.000089 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ & -0.000129 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  & -0.000141 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}
    \caption{Sesitivity of $x$.}
\end{table}

\subsubsection{$y_{1}$}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Max value of $y_{1}$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$}  \\
            \midrule
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  &  0.999839 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  &  0.000198 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  &  0.000151 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ &  0.000077 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.000009 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    & -0.000034 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  & -0.000035 \\
            $x_{0}$        & -0.000046 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ & -0.000093 \\
            $\beta_{2}$    & -0.000139 \\
            $g_{12}$       & -0.000249 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}\hfill
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Mean value of $y_{1}$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$}  \\
            \midrule
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.075955 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.002982 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  &  0.002090 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.001381 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    &  0.001270 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.000597 \\
            $x_{0}$        &  0.000273 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ &  0.000103 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  &  0.000057 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  & -0.000031 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ & -0.000053 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}\hfill
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Median value of $y_{1}$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$}  \\
            \midrule
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.072321 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.002983 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  &  0.001799 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.001496 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    &  0.001112 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.000621 \\
            $x_{0}$        &  0.000278 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  &  0.000067 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ &  0.000046 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ & -0.000025 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  & -0.000034 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}\hfill
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Eqm. value of $y_{1}$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$}  \\
            \midrule
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.070960 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.002951 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  &  0.001774 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.001540 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    &  0.001182 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.000605 \\
            $x_{0}$        &  0.000255 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ &  0.000077 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  &  0.000034 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ & -0.000012 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  & -0.000020 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}
    \caption{Sesitivity of $y_{1}$.}
\end{table}

\subsubsection{ $y_{2}$}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Max value of $y_{2}$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$}  \\
            \midrule
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.999839 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.000432 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  &  0.000172 \\
            $x_{0}$        &  0.000110 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ &  0.000104 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  &  0.000063 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ &  0.000018 \\
            $g_{12}$       & -0.000060 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    & -0.000154 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  & -0.000164 \\
            $\beta_{2}$    & -0.000174 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}\hfill
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Mean value of $y_{2}$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$}  \\
            \midrule
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.078556 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.004368 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.003232 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    &  0.001764 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.001399 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ &  0.000124 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  &  0.000072 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  &  0.000064 \\
            $x_{0}$        &  0.000063 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  & -0.000141 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ & -0.000146 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}\hfill
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Median value of $y_{2}$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$}  \\
            \midrule
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.075486 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.004046 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.003262 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    &  0.001588 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.001538 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ &  0.000075 \\
            $x_{0}$        &  0.000066 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  &  0.000063 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  &  0.000061 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  & -0.000132 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ & -0.000144 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}\hfill
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Eqm. value of $y_{2}$.}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
            {} &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$}  \\
            \midrule
            $\beta_{2}$    &  0.074109 \\
            ${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.003934 \\
            $g_{12}$       &  0.003281 \\
            $\beta_{1}$    &  0.001676 \\
            $\omega_{22}$  &  0.001576 \\
            $\epsilon_{2}$ &  0.000100 \\
            $\omega_{11}$  &  0.000069 \\
            $\gamma_{12}$  &  0.000043 \\
            $x_{0}$        &  0.000039 \\
            ${y_{1}}_{0}$  & -0.000113 \\
            $\epsilon_{1}$ & -0.000141 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}
    \caption{Sesitivity of $y_{2}$.}
\end{table}

\subsection{Delta Moment-Independent Measure}
\subsubsection{$x$}
\subsubsection{$y_{1}$}
\subsubsection{$y_{2}$}
\end{document}
```

In above MWE are in preamble considered only to problem relevant packaged. It gives the following result:

[image]

I hope that the proposed solution will also work in your real document.

Comment: What about using [H] instead of [ht] as mentioned here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Figures

Comment: If you like to have `[H]` use it, but using it you will have soon or later problems in formatting of document (a lot of white space when table will not fit on the available space on page). If this is not your concern, than use of `H` is OK.

Comment: I changed My [H] to [ht] and added the lines you mentioned . The subsections appears but I tested the method with my document which have other tables under other subsubsections of other subsections as in the example and all are mixed. some tables are under wrong subsections and not only under wrong subsubsection .

Comment: @F.O, than use `[H]` table placement.  Or not use `table` environment at all and use `captionof{table}{...}` instead of `caption`.