# titlesec explicit stops formatting of subsubsection

Tags: formatting, sectioning, titlesec

I need the explicit option for titlesec. However, when I set the explicit option, and also try to format subsubsections, they disappear. The same does not happen to subsections. Maybe I am using titleformat wrong, but it works for subsection, which is what is confusing me.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
    {\Huge\itshape}
    {#1}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\itshape\bfseries}
    {#1}{1em}{}


\titleformat{\subsubsection}
    {\normalfont\bfseries}
    {#1}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{SECTION}

\subsection{SUB}
Text before 

\subsubsection{SUBSUB}

Text after

\end{document}
```

For me at least, nothing appears between "Text before" and "Text after"

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Thank you for providing an MWE.

Comment: I'm unsure what the expected output should be. Can you add a sketch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MWE works correctly if you change the documentclass to `article`. Thus, I suspect that your issue stems from the fact that the `book` doesn't number subsubsections (`article` does). As a result, `\thesubsubsection` is presumably undefined. Assuming you do want subsubsections to be numbered, you can add

```latex
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```

to your code to increase the number of section levels that are numbered (suggested in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42161/numbering-subsubsection-in-report-class)).

[image: Working MWE with all section levels properly displayed]

Comment: Thanks for the input! Two points:

1. In reality, I am actually using a custom cls file provided to me. I am allowed to edit it - do you know how I can make the subsubsection numbered in a custom cls file?
2. Actually, even if I don't use \thesubsubsection, it still fails. I've updated the MWE accordingly. Does this make sense?

Comment: you can put `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` in your class file (it probably has such a setting already, to a lower value) @KHAAAAAAAAN

Comment: Hm, it already had \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}, and even using a higher number like 4 or 5 still shows nothing for subsubsection? Any other ideas for what it might be? (I understand its perhaps futile to ask for help without sharing the cls file itself, but I'm not sure about my ability to do so)

Comment: Ah, I found a workaround, to add "numberless" into the option for titleformat. That then makes it show up correctly.